# Comparing Dates to a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have 2 tables like this:**

```
USER
ID_____LastLogin
1------2013-12-19
2------2013-11-12
3------2013-09-14
4------2013-07-18
5------2013-06-13

OTHER
ID_____UserID___TimeStamp
1------1--------2013-12-17
2------2--------2013-10-11
3------3--------2013-05-14
4------4--------2013-02-18
```

I'm trying to get a count of the users that have logged in after 90 days since their "Other TimeStamp", if they are in that "other" table.

**Desired Results:**

```
2
```

**Desired Results explained:**

```
UserID of '1' LastLogin is not greater than Other.TimeStamp (excluded in count)
UserID of '2' LastLogin is not greater than Other.TimeStamp (excluded in count)
UserID of '3' LastLogin is greater than Other.TimeStamp (included in count)
UserID of '4' LastLogin is greater than Other.TimeStamp (included in count)
UserID of '5' is not in Other table (excluded in count)
```

**I've tried:**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user.ID))
FROM user INNER JOIN other ON other.UserID = User.ID
WHERE DATE(user.LastLogin) >= (
    SELECT (DATE(other.TimeStamp) + INTERVAL 90 DAY)
    FROM other
    GROUP BY other.UserID)
```

**I get an error that says:**

```
"Subquery returns more than 1 row"
```

I understand why the error is displaying (I can't compare a count to multiple rows of times of a subquery), though I'm trying to compare the count OF THOSE users.LastLogin to that same user's other.TimeStamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the subquery at all?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   user JOIN other ON other.UserID = user.ID
WHERE  user.LastLogin >= other.TimeStamp + INTERVAL 90 DAY
```

Comment: +1 . . . This is the better solution because it can use indexes on the datetime columns.  It does assume that the `other` table has only one row per `userid`, which seems like a reasonable assumption based on the question.

Comment: Sometimes I tend to over think a simple query :) Thank you

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. Is there a function which I could use in SQL Server to perform the exact same operation. I have tried with `datediff()`, but as you already said, it does not take advantage of the indexes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dada5/5)

You can use the `DATEDIFF()` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user 
INNER JOIN other ON other.UserID = User.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(user.Lastlogin,other.TimeStamp)>90
```

Comment: Good solution that I think would work as well. Though the >= works. Your idea of skipping the subquery is a good one too. Thank you.